# deactivate product-page image slider on mobile

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mobile, slideshow

I am developing a child theme of Storefront (WooCommerce). In the product page, I display all product images one above the other.

But the user can still swype right, as if the image slider is still active.

I would like to deactivated this swype motion on mobile (when the user swypes to the left, I want the product images not to move).

Can you help me achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, with this code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_hemen_theme_support', 100 );
function remove_hemen_theme_support() { 
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

The line `remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );` deactivate the slider.